# RegularExpressionValidator in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have search textbox,which has default value `Enter Month to View Profit`. When I click search button without entering any data, the default value of textbox is posted to server for search. I want that `RegularExpressionValidator` do not validate default value of textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Tboxsearch" Text="Enter Month to View Profit" OnClick="this.value=''"  CssClass="textboxinput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" CssClass="btnLog" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="ButtonSearch_Click" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator   
                             ID="RequiredFieldValidatorname"  
                             runat="server"  
                             ControlToValidate="Tboxsearch" 
                             ForeColor="Red"                            
                             Text="*"  
                             >  
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
                            ID="RegularExpressionValidatorname"  
                            runat="server"   
                            ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
                            ForeColor="Red"  
                            ControlToValidate="Tboxsearch"  
                            ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Name!"  
                            >  
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I see that you are using the RequiredFieldValidator which should prevent the postback

Answer (score 1):

The default for all validators except the RequiredFieldValidator control if you post with empty field the validator will not trigger

you must use required field validator with other validators to prevent the postback to happen

from MSDN

[Special-Case Validation Results for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6k4b2x3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

Also if you add your controls as in your question it should work but if there is other controls like for example other button you should set the validationGroup Property to the group that you want to work together

```
ValidationGroup="vGrp"
```

and your code will be like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Tboxsearch" Text="Enter Month to View Profit" OnClick="this.value=''" CssClass="textboxinput" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vGrp"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" CssClass="btnLog" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="ButtonSearch_Click" ValidationGroup="vGrp" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="RequiredFieldValidatorname"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="Tboxsearch"
    ForeColor="Red"
    Text="*"
    ValidationGroup="vGrp">  
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidatorname"
    runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ControlToValidate="Tboxsearch"
    ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Name!" ValidationGroup="vGrp"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

from MSDN about [validationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: please share any example

Comment: If you found my answer contain some ambiguity, please tell me so I can explain more

Comment: for the sake of acceptance, for the question to be complete and the answer to be accepted you need to check the answer with a check to appear accepted(will have a green check) and other viewer for your question know that that your problem has been solved by the checked answer so they would be benefit from it. thanks